# Get a error message "An unknown error has occurred" when create ad set

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I use java sdk(v2.9) to create ad set, and get this error message.

`{"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":""}}`

This is my code:

```
AdPromotedObject promotedObject = new AdPromotedObject();
promotedObject.setFieldApplicationId("1620089638283287");
account.createAdSet()
            .setName("AdSet01")
            .setBillingEvent(AdSet.EnumBillingEvent.VALUE_APP_INSTALLS)
            .setBidAmount(2L)
            .setDailyBudget(1000L)
            .setPromotedObject(promotedObject)
            .setCampaignId("23842591178760207")
            .setTargeting(
                    new Targeting()
                            .setFieldGeoLocations(new TargetingGeoLocation().setFieldCountries(Arrays.asList("US")))
            )
            .setStatus(AdSet.EnumStatus.VALUE_PAUSED)
            .execute();
```

Campaign id and app id is both exists and valid. I use the `account` create a campaign successfully so it is a valid account.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, i miss `object_store_url` field for `promotedObject`.

```
promotedObject.setFieldObjectStoreUrl("app url");
```